# Is there a way I can mutate an ip address in decimal format into normal human readable in logstash?

Tags: logstash

I am parsing a csv file in logstash which contains network traffic statistics.  These statistics report the ip address in decimal format.  I'd like to store them in logstash in dotted-quad (human readable) format.  Is there a way to do this via mutate?

Comment: What is "decimal" IP address format, if not identical to dotted-quad?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a clean wikipedia definition of it, but this webpage will sort of explain it: http://www.iowight.com/iwindex/decimal.php3

Comment: Ah, the 32 bits as a single integer.

Comment: In C, it's called an [inet_addr](http://publibn.boulder.ibm.com/doc_link/en_US/a_doc_lib/libs/commtrf2/inet_addr.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a ruby filter like this:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => 'event["ip_as_dotted_quad"] = [event["your_field_here"].to_i].pack("N").unpack("C4").join(".")'
  }
}
```

You'll just need to fill in `your_field_here`. If you already converted the field to an integer, you can leave out the `.to_i`.

(credit where credit is due -- I found the ip address snippet at the bottom of this page: http://basic70tech.wordpress.com/2007/04/13/32-bit-ip-address-to-dotted-notation-in-ruby/ but adapted it to use here.)

Comment: It's a few years later, but this helped when trying to turn a protobuf byte-string into a useful format.

Answer (score 1):

In Logstash 7.9.x this is what works:

```
filter {
    ruby { code => '
        input = event.get("your_field_here").to_i;
        result = IPAddr.new(input, Socket::AF_INET).to_s;
        event.set("ip_as_dotted_quad", result);
        '
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Aaron Nimocks for this code.